# how to get an input test signal for convolution/ distortion method

Tags: python, deconvolution, distortion

i am trying to do some experiments with Total Harmonic Distortion.
According to [`Simultaneous measurement of impulse response and distortion with a swept-sine technique`](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2456363_Simultaneous_Measurement_of_Impulse_Response_and_Distortion_With_a_Swept-Sine_Technique)

i have to use the deconvolution method to get distortion harmonics.
The problem i have is that i don have any experience with the mathematics behind deconvolution. So i want to test it with some known signals.
but i have the problem i need thus some signals with known distortion to try out... How do i make this kind of signals.

- Input signals

  - sine wave ?
  - chirp
- added distortion

  - specific filters
  - sine waves
  - chirp ( how to add this frequency specific...)

I use python with numpy and scipy

Comment: do you want to filter those signals to get the distortion and study it?

Comment: Experiment with THD? One technically acknowledged definition of THD is distortion due to clipping, which produces harmonic overtones as distortion terms. Is your problem related to THD or deconvolution algorithm. Btw why do you "have" to use deconvolution, and for what purpose here ?

Comment: according to to the referred document i can use the swept-sine technique to measure and calculate back the harmonic distortion.
They use the deconvolution technique to calculate the distortion harmonics (via a set of impulse responses). I want to try this out on my speaker system. But before this i have to be sure that what i do is right. and therefore i asked this question...